# [RestAssured][Allure] Could't render http attachment file

Tags: attachment, rest-assured, allure, java-17

I have a problem with my test suit. After made a request I didnt see response in logs and Allure can not render http attachment file. Only have request body in logs

I use Java 17 and suit is building by Jenkins. Strange thing is when I run this suit from IDE or localy by maven command everything is ok and when I run it by Jenkins i have this problem.

Maybe sameone have similar problem?

**CODE**

```
protected Response delete(ApiRequestModel apiRequestModel) {
    return given()
        .spec(apiConnector.authorize())
        .filter(new AllureRestAssured())
        .headers(apiRequestModel.getHeaders())
        .body(apiRequestModel.getRequestBody())
        .when()
        .log()
        .all()
        .delete(apiRequestModel.getEndpoint())
        .then()
        .log()
        .all()
        .statusCode(apiRequestModel.getStatusCode())
        .extract()
        .response();
}
```

**Dependency version**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <allure.testng.version>2.21.0</allure.testng.version>
    <allure.maven.version>2.10.0</allure.maven.version>
    <allure.rest-assured.version>2.21.0</allure.rest-assured.version>
    <allure.report.version>2.12.0</allure.report.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin-version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
    <rest-assured.version>5.1.1</rest-assured.version>
    <testng.version>7.6.1</testng.version>
    <jackson.version>2.14.1</jackson.version>
    <json.version>20210307</json.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.19</aspectj.version>
  </properties>
```

**LOGS**

```
io.qameta.allure.attachment.AttachmentRenderException: Could't render http attachment file
    at io.qameta.allure.attachment.FreemarkerAttachmentRenderer.render(FreemarkerAttachmentRenderer.java:49)
    at io.qameta.allure.attachment.FreemarkerAttachmentRenderer.render(FreemarkerAttachmentRenderer.java:28)
    at io.qameta.allure.attachment.DefaultAttachmentProcessor.addAttachment(DefaultAttachmentProcessor.java:41)
    at io.qameta.allure.restassured.AllureRestAssured.filter(AllureRestAssured.java:103)


Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: start 160, end 0, length 161
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.checkRange(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1802)
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:680)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:393)
    at java.base/java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:122)
    at freemarker.template.utility.StringUtil.XMLOrHTMLEnc(StringUtil.java:215)
    at freemarker.template.utility.StringUtil.XHTMLEnc(StringUtil.java:105)
    at freemarker.core.HTMLOutputFormat.output(HTMLOutputFormat.java:62)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:68)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:347)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:353)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:353)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:326)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:383)
    at io.qameta.allure.attachment.FreemarkerAttachmentRenderer.render(FreemarkerAttachmentRenderer.java:46)
```

I tried to:

- any variations of dependency version
- clear maven local repository
- change Java version to 11
- commented log().all() line
- attached filter section to RequestSpecification
- remove filter section

Comment: I have same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by switching to the new java version

```
java 17.0.8 2023-07-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing)
```